# How to Fit in Training Scheduele

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu

So I have recently taken up BJJ.  I have only taken a couple of classes but would love to go almost every day.  The only problem is that my current gyms class schedule doesn't fit in with my work and my school schedule.  I've tried looking for other gyms in the area, but they all seem to have very similar schedules.  What would be a good way to go about this?  Should I go to open mats which are usually in the morning (I work at night)?  Or is that annoying to the more experienced people?  I don't want to go to open mats either and hurt myself or someone else because I don't know what I'm doing either.

Comment: I'll just say I don't think your case is unique. It's actually common to have difficult or impossible schedules. If you work at night, that's when most martial arts schools have classes. Your other two options are morning and afternoon classes. A third option would be private lessons once or twice a week, and do open mat in the mornings to practice what you learned. You may even be able to get a small number of others to do group lessons (cheaper than private lessons). No, you should not do open mat unless you already have someone training you. They're not there to teach you. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and I forgot weekends. Many schools have classes on the weekends. That's also when private lessons tend to go on. If your schedule allows it, that might work for you. You could even do one regular class and a private lesson the same weekend. Then weekdays you could do open gym in the mornings. Something to think about.